# Pull only one item in an array of instance in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working with MongoDB (by using Mongoose on NodeJS).

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5fa4386f3a93dc470c920d76"},
"characters":[
    {"$oid":"5fa4389e3a93dc470c920d78"},
    {"$oid":"5fa4389e3a88888888888888"},
    {"$oid":"5fa4389e3a88888888888888"},
    {"$oid":"5fa4389e3a88888888888888"}
    ]
}
```

I tried to remove only one row of object id "5fa4389e3a88888888888888" in my characters array.
By doing..

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate("5fa4386f3a93dc470c920d76", { $pull: { characters: "5fa4389e3a88888888888888" } }, (err) => {});
```

The problem is that every row with "5fa4389e3a88888888888888" value are removed.
And I'd just like to pull 1.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), and use the [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) operator to define custom functions to implement behavior not supported by the MongoDB Query Language. Starting from MongoDB v4.4,

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate("5fa4386f3a93dc470c920d76",
[
    {
        $set: {
            characters: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(characters) {
                        for (var i=0; i<characters.length; i++) {
                            if (characters[i] == "5fa4389e3a88888888888888") {
                                delete characters[i];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        return characters;
                    },
                    args: ["$characters"],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```